# Как правильно организовать загрузку данных на клиент с сервера

Tags: java

Пишу что-то вроде сервис-деска. При каждом входе клиента в аккаунт сервер передает ему все назначенные задачи(таски) за последний месяц (и выполненные, и невыполненные).
Собственно, вопрос: нормальна ли такая ситуация? Если нет, как правильно организовать передачу, что бы не передавать каждый раз все таски?

UPD: клиент - десктопное приложение.

UPD2: решил сделать кнопку и принудительно обновлять по 20 штук. Всем спасибо!

Comment: нормальна ли такая ситуация? Кто же знает, кроме Вас. как правильно организовать передачу, что бы не передавать каждый раз все таски? Сделать что то типа пагинации.

Comment: Я надеюсь, что есть опытные люди, которые знают, как должна организовываться такая работа в приложении. Я новичок в программировании, однако, слышал, что изобретение велосипеда - не лучший способ построения программ. П.С. приложение десктопное.

Comment: @ferZ, если бы все приложения писались на основании чужого кода, то зачем нужны были бы программисты? Все и всегда пишут свои велосипеды, так устроен мир программирования. Поэтому, сначала попробуйте сами реализовать, и если что-то не получится - возвращайтесь с конкретной проблемой.

Comment: @ferZ, тут нет провидцев и умеющих читать чужие мысли. Хотите более развернутый ответ? Откуда кому то знать что должно делать ваше приложение и нормальна ли ситуация, когда все данные выводятся сразу? На второй ваш вопрос я ответил.

Comment: @DmitriyD, я ж не прошу чужой код) Я просто хочу узнать от более опытных людей, нормально ли, когда при запуске программы сервак начинает подгружать на клиента сотни "задач", или надо сразу думать о каком то их хранении на клиенте локально. Я не знаю, как поведет себя программа, когда условно утром в 9:00 в сеть зайдут почти одновременно 200 клиентов и серваку потребуется каждому отправить их задачи (которых может быть условно до сотни включая выполненные за месяц). Нормальная ли это практика, такое делается в приложениях, или сразу думать о каком то другом решении?

Comment: Нормальная практика у нормальных программистов - это использование пагинации. О чём вам сообщили в первом комментарии. Ещё вопросы?

Comment: @AlekseiGaile, спасибо, вопрос решил! Сделайте, пожалуйста, ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Программирование - творческий процесс. Здесь нет никогда конкретного решения и в разных ситуациях есть более подходящие решения. Переменных, которое на это влияет - огромное множество, начиная от количества людей, которые будут использовать, заканчивая мощностью сервера. Та же пагинация - это не 100% решение. Помимо этого есть и кеширование. Которое может быть не только на клиенте, но и на сервере. И много много разных других способов сделать эту задачу. Какой из них выбрать, как раз и является работой программиста.

Comment: @NocteFury, я понимаю. Но конкретно в моем случае кеширование не подойдет, я уже об этом думал. А вот подходящего способа придумать не мог. Почитав про панигацию понял, что это подходит для меня. Собственно, это мне и нужно было - совет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких целей подходит пагинация. В общем виде - строится запрос к БД с выборкой необходимых и достаточных для отображения на пользовательском интерфейсе части данных. Запрос формируется по параметрам - номер страницы и размер списка для отображения. Для примера -

```
select * from your_table limit :pageSize offset :page
```

При выборе следующей страницы пользователям, на бэкенд отправляется номер страницы, которую хочет увидеть пользователь.